# New evidence against the existence of dark matter?

Tags: gravity, dark-matter

I've just read and heard about an article which gives new evidence for [MOND - Modified Newtonian Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics), which is an alternative to dark matter by proposing that our gravitational law should be modified, and with it evidence *against* the dark matter hypothesis. I was first brought to attention on this by a video by Dr. Becky on Youtube:

Here is the article itself:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/abbb96

And a few other articles on the discovery:

http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/modified-gravity-theory-09165.html
https://www.universetoday.com/149416/new-data-supports-the-modified-gravity-explanation-for-dark-matter-much-to-the-surprise-of-the-researchers/
https://newatlas.com/physics/modified-gravity-evidence-dark-matter/

Does anybody know more about this? Isn't this quite significant? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I am sure you know e.g. about https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/hubble-detects-smallest-known-dark-matter-clumps as a rather recent example of evidence *for* dark matter, [CDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_dark_matter) to be exact.

Comment: Well, like Dr. Smethurst says in the video, there are tons of evidence *for* dark matter. *One* study saying otherwise is not much to call home about. Like her, I would like to see a similar study done, not on 153 galaxies, but on *thousands* of galaxies.

Comment: @PierrePaquette Yeah, of course, but I was just wondering how much significance this article actually had. But yes, it's gonna be interesting to see the results in a bigger study!

Comment: @B--rian Thank you, maybe I'll check it out :)

Comment: @Physics2718 The immediate significance is sometimes pointless. Even Einstein’s original article on the theory of relativity („Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper” or in English “On the electrodynamics of moving bodies”) went under the radar at first. (I’m not saying the paper you refer to will have the same impact…)

Comment: For anyone looking for a bit of context: this is about a study claiming a detection of an External Field Effect, which is in violation of the Strong Equivalence Principle predicted by GR, but is a keystone prediction of a theory like MOND.  MOND has a lot of issues explaining a number of observations, like the Bullet Cluster, though.